# referencing something from global namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces

This is really trivial but I'm getting an error I didn't expect.

I have some code which is inside of a namespace

the following is some pseudocode that represents the structure of my code:

```
namespace A {
    void init() {
        initialize_kitchen_sink();
    }
    #include "operations.h" // declares shake_and_bake()
    void foo() {            
        shake_and_bake();
    }
    void cleanup() {
        // do nothin' cuz i'm a slob
    }
}
```

error:

```
undefined reference to `A::shake_and_bake`
```

Comment: Everything in the operations.h file is being declared in the namespace A. If you include the file operations.h in another file but in a different namespace (such as global) these will be completely different declarations. Note the #include is part of the pre-processor and does its operation long before any language constructs get done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out moving the `#include` outside the namespace will fix it.

As it was, the include would be in effect declaring all of the functions in `operations.h` inside the `A` namespace. Then it would search in vain for the implementations.

I figure instead of deleting my entire post i may as well leave it for that minute possibility that someone else may stumble upon a similar problem and be enlightened.

Comment: better yet, try to put your includes at the top of a source file, rather than in the middle where you first need the logic

Comment: I haven't seen any proper reason for not putting includes at the top. I still sometimes mess this up, though for example if I put my unit tests at the bottom, the `#include "unittest++.h"` may end up near the end of the file before all the unit test macros. So that seems to work fine but is probably also bad form. Possibly

Answer (score 6):

To answer precisely to your question, you can reference something from the global namespace by using :: as your first statement as in :

```
 void foo() {            
        ::shake_and_bake();
    }
```

Of course, your answer, for this special case is right though.

Comment: I didn't know you could do that. Is the only situation in which this would be useful the one where something with the same name is declared both in global namespace and the current namespace?

Comment: That's also how I understand it. I know however, that framworks like gtest (google unit tests framwork) heavilly rely on it, so there must be some cases where you don't have any other choice ! Koenig Lookup can be complicated sometimes :)

Comment: It's neat to look at answers to my own questions from years ago and still learn things. Koenig Lookup is cool, I've been using it for a while.